# Debugger.Launch not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-4.0

I am currently trying to launch a debugger for a process that is launched externally (not from within visual studio). I cannot seem to get a debugger actually launch, as it appears nothing happens. In the process, I added this code:

```
Debug.Assert(Debugger.IsAttached == false, "Should be no debugger");
if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Debug.Assert(Debugger.Launch(), "Debugger not launched");
}
Debugger.Break();
Debug.Assert(Debugger.IsAttached == true, "Debugger should be attached");
```

The asserts are there to verify that I'm not crazy. At first, the *IsAttached* property returns false as I expect. I then call *Debugger.Launch*, and that returns **true**. As per the MSDN documentation of *Debugger.Launch*, it says it will only return true if it succeeds in launching the debugger, or if one is already attached. I verified one was not attached, so it must have launched one.

The break-point never gets hit, and the second verify fails (the *IsAttached* property returns false). I also attempted to put a sleep in after *Debugger.Launch* to give it some time, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Something wrong with your vsjitdebugger setup.  Try this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/9a539c40-1869-44b8-9aed-9f9d7d402d7c/  If that doesn't help then use ProcMon and compare a good machine with the bad one.

Comment: Good to know about the tags. I'll try out the article Hans and see what I can find.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have the same problem in Visual Studio 2013 Premium. [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132357/eric)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463190) put me over how to resolve it. But you don't need to change the register.

1. Go to Tools --> Options --> Debugging
2. Open the item and select just  in time debugger
3. If you see in the low part of the window a yellow
   warning about that other debug is being used different to Visual
   Studio. If you see that, check all Just in Time checkboxes to return
   to VS to be the debug program.

That is all!

[image: Options Just in Time debugger]

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Just In Time Debugger almost daily, but one day it stopped working and mentioned checkboxes were unchecked - i.e. something disabled it. I don't have any idea what though.

Comment: Also  check that "just in time debugger" is installed by visual studio.

Answer (score 6):

Even though [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770786/just-in-time-debugging-operation-attempted-is-not-supported#tabs) article says the issue is solved in VS2013, even if you are using VS2013 like me, look for the temporary fixes tab listed there. I fixed the issue using it. More info in the link.

I'll just link [another article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a539c40-1869-44b8-9aed-9f9d7d402d7c/mysterious-vs-jit-debugger-invocation-failure?forum=vsdebug&prof=required) which put me in the right direction, perhaps it's useful too.

**Summary:** Change the AppIDFlags value of the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger registry key from 0x28 to 0x8 (or 0x20 according to the article above, trial and error I guess) They registry key is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{E62A7A31-6025-408E-87F6-81AEB0DC9347}

Comment: This worked for me with VS 2017 Professional! I changed it from 0x28 to 0x8.

Comment: It also worked for VS 2012 Professional. I changed it from 0x28 to 0x8. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this will helps someone in the future. I had the same issue, that Debugger.Launch didn't appear to do anything. Turns out that someone else was logged into my machine and the debugger attach promped launched in their environment, not mine. I kicked them out of the system and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019 first verify Just in time debugger installed.

[image: VS Installer]

then enable just in time debugger in Options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by a combination of things mentioned here (and related answers).  Maybe this will lead some folks to a quicker resolution.

1. I saw in Visual Studio, in Tools > Options > Debugging > Just-In-Time, all three options were unchecked, and the "warning" below read "Another debugger has registered itself...".  Checking them and saving did not solve the problem (running a Administrator and not).
2. When I ran the Visual Studio Installer, I saw that "Visual Studio Build Tools 2017" was installed for some reason (possible I installed it and just not remembered).  I didn't need it, so I uninstalled it and rebooted.
3. Ran Visual Studio as Administrator, checked all three of those options, clicked "OK" and it worked.