# How do I debug a program when launched as a process?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, constructor

I have two programs in Visual Studio. One opens the other with Process.Start with arguments. I know how to attach to a process that is running, but not one being launched.

How do I debug the secondary process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5514248/17034

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Debugger.Break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method in the program you want to debug, and the debugger will be launched at that line of code. Also you can try [Debugger.Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I just tried it and it did not launch vs or break there. Vs was already opened with that program. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you added the line of code in a sequence where it can be reached? Also you can try Debugger.Launch()

Comment: It should have been accessible, it did run the code around where i put it. I'll try the launch method.

Comment: Please, let me knos if it works, I have used this method, and if it's called when the program is executed, it launches the compiler at that line of code.

Comment: Neither of these methods work for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know you tend to drop them, by what have you tried? Has the method been called, are you sure of that?

Comment: Yes, i am sure of that.

Comment: @DonA You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655965/debugger-launch-not-working), you may have a version of Visual Studio which does not support Debugger.Lauch method.