# Windows Service and System File Watcher

Tags: c#, windows, service, file-watcher

I have to use a system file Watcher into a Windows service.
I write a wrap class and I put it into the service class as shown below :

```
public partial class CaptureRecordingsService : ServiceBase
{

    FileSystemWatcherWrapper myFSWrapper;

    public CaptureRecordingsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        myFSWrapper = new FileSystemWatcherWrapper();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }        
 }
}
```

The class works done in Windows form but in the service the methods are not called.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what did you expect to happen? has the service been installed and does it show up in the windows services snap-in? or are you using the project templates' scaffolding that simulates a service start in the debugger?

Comment: @Fildor could be https://github.com/mbenford/FileSystemWatcherWrapper. or not ;-) I would suggest adding a [mcve]

Comment: or [this problem launching the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12655965/1132334). is the service running as a different user than the interactive session?

Comment: @bradbury9 Meh, yeah. Missed the tag ...

Comment: Or not setting the path to monitor in the FileSystemWatcher

Comment: I solved the problem inoking the filesystemwrapper in a new thread.