# How to debug a C# console application after it has been activated by SSIS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package project that will pass a variable into an Execute Process Task.  This task is a C# Console application project that I have set to Debug mode. Both of these projects are part of the same Visual Studio 2019 solution.

Although I place several breakpoints throughout the C# code, they never get hit.  The SSIS package successfully triggers the console application which then executes successfully without error.

Is there a way to configure SSIS and/or Visual Studio so that the breakpoints in the Console App can be used for debugging?

Comment: If visual studio isn't directly executing the console app you'd need to wait till the console app is running and then attach the debugger to the executable process.

Comment: (But if you just want to test the console app, then test it directly and pass in a variable to it as a test value.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: One way to solve your problem is to use method [Debugger.Launch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655965/debugger-launch-not-working). Just place call of this method where you want to break execution of your application and then continue its debugging.